# How to get canadian cross build of Clang 3.8

Tags: linux, clang, mingw-w64

Does anybody tried to get canadian cross build of LLVM\Clang 3.8 ?

I'm trying to build clang on ubuntu 16.04 using mingw-w64 for windows host assuming final target is ARM or PowerPC.

I already experienced following issues:
1. https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26365 (workaround – patch sources)
2. https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25953 (workaround - "-Wa,-mbig-obj")

But still have no luck.

Is there any chance to get it working without native build on windows machine ?

Thank you in advance